# How can I reverse this function in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I made a mute command, but cannot figure out what steps to take to remove the role "Muted" when "%unmute @user" is typed. This is the code for the mute command:

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
@bot.command(name='mute', help='Use %help mute to see full description... Mutes the mentioned user by adding a role to them. If the role is absent, the bot will make one. Requires permissions: Manage Messages')
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")

    if not mutedRole:
        mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")

        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="muted", description=f"{member.mention} was muted ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
    embed.add_field(name="reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)
    await member.send(f" you have been muted from: {guild.name} reason: {reason}")
```

Thank you!

Comment: I may have figured this out. I need a sec...

Comment: If you figure it out, make sure to post your solution as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out! Here is the resulting code:

```
@bot.command(name='unmute', help='Unmutes the mentioned user. Requires permissions: Manage Messages')
async def unmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")

    embed = discord.Embed(title="unmuted", description=f"{member.mention} was unmuted ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
    await member.send(f" you have been unmuted from: {guild.name}")
```

Sorry for bothering you guys!